# Recuperando dados no Firebase Android com classe

Tags: firebase, realtime-database

Tenho esta estrutura de banco que é esta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha classe tenho um função chamada getLocal (), onde ela pegaria o nome Iguatemi. desta estrutura. Porem ao realizar a query ele esta retornando como null.

Segue minha clase com as funções abaixo:

```
public class Mesa {

private String ID;
private String Local;
private DatabaseReference reference;
private String NFC;

public Mesa() {
}

public void Salvar(){
    DatabaseReference reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia();
    reference.child("Mesas").child(getID()).setValue(this);
}

@Exclude
public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public void setID() {
    reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia().child("Mesas");
    this.ID = reference.push().getKey();
}

public String getLocal(String Txt) {
    DatabaseReference reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia();
    reference.child("Mesas").child(Txt).child("local");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String texto = (String) dataSnapshot.getKey();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });

        return Local;
}

public void setLocal(String local) {
    Local = local;
}
```

}

Por favor me ajudem com o que eu estou errando.

Para ficar melhor a pergunta vou colocar como estou fazendo na Activity.

```
package meals.com.meals.activity.Activity;
```

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

import meals.com.meals.R;
import meals.com.meals.activity.modelo.Mesa;

import static meals.com.meals.R.array.Restaurante_KFC_Pratos;
import static meals.com.meals.R.array.Restaurante_McDonalds_Pratos;

public class FazerPedido extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView InfoMesa;
private Spinner SpinnerRestaurante;
private Spinner SpinnerPratos;
private Mesa Mesas;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fazer_pedido);

    InfoMesa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewInfoMesa);
    SpinnerRestaurante = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerRestaurante);
    SpinnerPratos = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_pratos);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    String NFC = bundle.getString("TagNFC");

    Mesa Mesas = new Mesa();
    Mesas.RecuperarMesa(NFC);

    InfoMesa.setText("Você esta em " + Mesas.getLocal() + " " + "na mesa \n" + NFC);
   // InfoMesa.setText("Você esta na na mesa \n" + NFC);



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chame `dataSnapshot.getValue()`para acessar os dados.
E é boas práticas verificar se`dataSnapshop.exists()` antes de chamar.

Se não existir, é porque você está acessando uma `child` vazia.

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshop.exists()){
            Mesa mesa = dataSnapshot.getValue(Mesa.class);

            //Faça o que quiser com o objeto.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("TAG", databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Sempre que for salvar e retornar dados pelo Firebase, crie um Getter simples pra todas as variáveis que for recuperar. Assim como fez com a ID, mas com o Local também.

Assim como você tem um método `public void Salvar()`, crie um `public Mesa Recuperar()` que vai baixar a Mesa assim como você fez. Retorne essa Mesa.

```
public Mesa Recuperar(){
    Mesa mMesa = new Mesa();
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshop.exists()){
                mMesa = dataSnapshot.getValue(Mesa.class);

                //Faça o que quiser com o objeto.
            }
        }
    return mMesa;
}
```

E tendo o getter simples para o local da classe Mesa.

```
public String getLocal() {
    return local;
}
```

Assim, se quiser acessar o local, é só chamar `mMesa.getLocal()` e fazer o que quiser, como salvar numa variável global ou retornar.

Comment: se eu quiser pegar o Nome do local em String e retornar, como ficaria?
Pois como estou pegando A classe Mesa.class eu iria pegar tudo né?

Comment: O método "getLocal()" deveria ser um método getter comum. E aí você poderia chamar o mesa.getLocal() para ter acesso a String retornada por ele. E recuperar os dados do banco de dados através de um método separado, que retornaria uma Mesa.

Comment: acho que sou muito burro, não sei se pode passar um email ou algo do tipo para vc me ajudar mais..... segue o meu ai 19 997749701 pode me chamar

Comment: Dentro do Mesa recuperar eu coloquei esta parte do codigo a mais pois tenho que procurar através do ID

`public Mesa RecuperarMesa (String Txt){`
 `Mesa mesa = new Mesa();`
`DatabaseReference reference =ConfiguracaoFirebase.getReferencia();`
        `reference.child("Mesas").equalTo(Txt);`

Comment: Pelo que seu código mostra, você salvou a mesa usando o ID. Então para procurar usando o ID é só dar um reference.child("Mesas").child(ID). Com isso você já tem a referência da mesa com o ID que você quer.